What does "trap: SIGINT: bad trap" mean and how do I fix it?
I moved code to a new virtual server running Ubuntu 22.
I have the following (edited to make names shorter) in my crontab so that it runs myCommand only if it is not already running:
*/1 * * * * cusack flock -x -n ~myLock myCommand >> ~my.log 2>&1
When it runs, it puts trap: SIGINT: bad trap in my logfile. It did not do this on the old server. Am I doing something wrong?
My goal is, as alluded to above, to just have one copy of myCommand running at a time. If it is still running from the last time, it should do nothing. Other posts led me to believe that this was a proper way to do this, and it worked on my old server. So why does it give me this error message?
I tried adding a "-E 0" thinking that a 0 might mean everything is OK as it does in some contexts, but that didn't work. I added "-x", which didn't work and shouldn't change anything since according to the documentation it is the default anyway.

Which shell does myCommand specify as its interpreter?  Is this a different shell in the new Ubuntu 22.x server compared to the old server?

What happens if you run it in a terminal? If it works there, you are tripping over the different runtime environments. Check $PATH in each environment.

@waltinator When I run it on the command line it outputs nothing (as I desire).

@SottoVoce  It uses #!/bin/sh

Does this answer your question? Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?

Is cusack a username? If you've put this entry in your crontab, you won't have a username field. That's only for the system crontabs under /etc

Based on the information you gave in comments, your old server probably used an older release of Ubuntu with bash as the /bin/sh shell.  Bash supports signal names like HUP and SIGHUP as arguments to its builtin trap command.  More recent versions of Ubuntu use dash as the /bin/sh shell, and Dash's trap command supports signal names like HUP, but not SIGHUP.  This is what the error message is telling you.
You have a choice of solutions:

Edit your script's trap command to remove the SIG prefix from the signal names, so it conforms to the Dash shell's syntax.
Change the first line of the script to call bash (i.e., make it: #!/bin/bash).

My suggestion would be to use the second option because if your script has one Bash-ism in its commands/syntax, then it likely has others and there will be more errors and edits to make it Dash compatible.  Instead, one edit ensures that you'll keep running it with a Bash shell.

First, so far this seems to have worked! Second, I am an idiot--I didn't know where the trap stuff was coming from, but I finally looked back at the script that was being called and there it is! I just assumed the script was calling a python script, but I set it up to run a few copies and used a trap to do it I guess (I wrote it 2 years ago and promptly forgot about the details of that script).

I should be more specific--I changed sh to bash and it now works as expected.
